# Отправка писем через SMTP Outlook. Python

Tags: python, smtp, outlook

Осуществляю отправку писем через smtp outlook (Python).

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText


_from = "my_mail@my_name.domen"
_from_pass = "my_pass"

smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp-mail.outlook.com', 587)
smtpObj.starttls()
smtpObj.ehlo()
smtpObj.login(_from,_from_pass)
```

Почта отправителя - корпоративная. В настройках пользователя уже стоит разрешение для использования этого ящика через SMTP

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако на строчке smtpObj.login вылетает ошибка smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful)

(При попытках отправить письма с другого ящика, не корпоративного, этот же код работает без ошибки)

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно исправить это?

Comment: А у пользователя точно работает взаимодействие с внешним корпоративным Exchange-сервером - в другом клиенте, например, MS Outlook, Mz Thuderbird, etc.? Я сталкивался с такой фигнёй, что почтовый сервер Exchange не работал с пользовательским паролем, в котором использовалась кириллица :-(

Comment: @Daemon-5 , да, работает

Comment: А пробовали авторизоваться логином ,а не "мылом"? Т.е. **_from = "login_name"** или **_from = "domain\login_name"**

Comment: @Daemon-5, да, опробовала - не работает

Comment: Может в процессе аутентификации Вы "забыли" представиться серверу - команду SMTP.ehlo пробовали добавить до запуска TLS ?

Comment: @Daemon-5, да, эта команда прописана, в коде моего вопроса эту строчку упустила просто

пробовала её прописать и до  запуска TLS, и после, и сразу до и после :)
не помогает

Comment: @МарияМамонова у вас получилось решить проблему?